# Move logo to center of page

Tags: layout, magento-2.1

I want to move LOGO of site to center and want to add some text on the place of logo. I am able to add text from file but logo is not moving to center of container.

- I have extended LUMA theme.
- Screen Shot is attached as what i want achieve

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do it modifying element style; try to change *.logo* style (`margin: -8px auto 25px 30%;` instead of `margin: -8px auto 25px 0;`), for example.

In this case, you have to hook your text block in another block, different from **logo**.

Comment: it would not work.

Comment: I tried it and it works fine.

Comment: This is not a proper way to movo logo to center and Add static block in left side.  I am looking to use of standard magento way

Comment: Logo element is in **header.container** block, correctly.
In there, you have two inline elements (_nav-toggle_ and _logo_) and two block elements (_minicart-wrapper_ and _block-seearch_); thier positions are decided by style only.
My advice is Magento complient.

Comment: If i do this, then I can display text on left side of logo? 1st: "Some Text", 2nd: Logo, 3rd: Search-box.

Comment: Of course.. as I wrote: in your **default.xml** you should declare your block under `<referenceContainer name="header.container">` to print it first of **logo** block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50190/discussion-between-jai-and-wapone).

Comment: Isn't giving an arbitrary value for margin left e.g. 30% in order to center something, somehow suggests that we are giving a fixed value? Wouldn't better if there was a solution that doesn't depend on the dimension of the logo in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try achieve this by following code.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<container name="header.main" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="header-main">
    <container name="header.main.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
        <container name="header.main.row" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row vcenter">
            <container name="header.main.social" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-3 col-sm-3 hidden-xs header-social" before="-">
                <block name="header.social" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/social.phtml"/>
            </container>
            <container name="header.main.logo" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-10 header-logo">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">499</argument>
                        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">57</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
            <container name="header.main.search" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-3 col-sm-3 header-search hidden-xs" after="-">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
            </container>
        </container>
    </container>
</container>
```